# Proof $P\left(\limsup_n \{\sum_i X_i > \sqrt{\alpha n \log (n)}\}\right)= 0$ where $X_i$ independent, normally distributed

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, normal-distribution

I'm trying to solve this exam prep question: Let $X_i$ be independent and $\mathscr{N}_{0,1}$ distributed. Let $\alpha > 2$. Show that
$$P\left(\limsup_n \{\sum_i^n X_i > \sqrt{\alpha n \log (n)}\}\right)= 0$$
This looks strongly like Borel-Cantelli's Lemma, so I wanted to show that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty P\left(\sum_i^n X_i > \sqrt{\alpha n \log (n)}\right) < \infty$$
I don't know how this can be shown though, as Chebyshev-Markov won't work because the $X_i$ are normally distributed, i.e., we can't just use the absolute value function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*HINT* using that $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n X_i = \xi_n \sim N(0,n)$. Note that

$$\mathbb{P}(\xi_n > \sqrt{\alpha n\log(n)}) \le e^{-\frac{\alpha n \log{n}}{n}} = \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}$$

This is *upper deviation inequality*